# How to query search result from mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have made a product uploading from and it works successfully. But now I want to create a search form so that anyone can show result by searching product title or category or price. My table contains title, price, description, category column.

My code is not working. I am not sure how to do it right way. When I wanted to add more column it is not working. I am definitely not sure what is the wrong or what should I need to do.

Here is my code for product searching:

```
 <?php

 // Connects to your Database 
         mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
         mysql_select_db("product") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
         $search =$_POST['search'];
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manage WHERE title or category and price= '$search' ") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //Puts it into an array 
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
     //Outputs the image and other data 
     echo "<img src=http://localhost/hasem/exresze/images/".$info['photo'] ."> <br>"; Echo "<b>Title:</b> ".$info['title'] . "<br> "; Echo "<b>Description:</b> ".$info['description'] . " <br>"; Echo "<b>Category:</b> ".$info['category'] . " <hr>"; }

     ?> 

    <form action="search_product.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
     ?>
```

I have tried many time to get result by putting more column name into my query code but not working. It only supports two columns . Please give me a perfect idea so that i can get it proper way. Please don't mind i am new to this field.This query code works fine

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manage WHERE title or category = '$search' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What code do you have for the search option? You need to try to code first, then ask for help on the code, not just ask for code. To give you a starter: get the user input from a form, SELECT in the database where what they entered matches something in the DB. Validate and sanitise their inputs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this. This will search for the given title OR category OR price.

You basically need a search query like this

```
SELECT 
title, price, description, category, photo 
FROM `manage` 
WHERE 
title LIKE '%$title%' OR 
price LIKE '%$price%' OR  
category LIKE '%$category%'
```

You can do more optimization on this code. It is up to you to do the filtering.

```
<?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 


 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $title=$_POST['title']; 
 $price=$_POST['price']; 

 $category=$_POST['category']; 


 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("product") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 


mysql_query("SELECT title, price, description, category, photo FROM `manage` WHERE title LIKE '%$title%' OR price LIKE '%$price%' OR  category LIKE '%$category%' ") ; 
//Handle the result
 ?> 

<div id="contact">
    <h1>Add New Product.</h1>
    <form action="admin.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="title">Product Title<span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="name" placeholder="Enter your product title" /> 
            <label for="price">Product Price $<span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="name" placeholder="Enter your product price" />         
            <label for="category">Product Category <span>*</span></label>
            <select name="category" id = "myList">
               <option value = "Cloth">Cloths</option>
               <option value = "Honda">Honda</option>
               <option value = "Book">Book</option>
               <option value = "Computer">Computer</option>
             </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Note**: This is pseudo code that I edited from your code.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you would need a query like this: (i added description in the search_string also, it is a common practice).

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `manage` WHERE `title` LIKE "%$search_string%" OR `description` LIKE "%$search_string" OR (`price`>$min_price AND `price`<$max_price') OR `category`=$category);
```

Not tested, but shouldn't be hard to get it working. Also you should do "AND" statements with additional logic if you want to narrow down your filter by multiple fields.

You may want to use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli), or this will not work on php 5.5

Also, usualy it is better to check if the file was uploaded before you make a database entry, unless you want to make the record anyway.